# fsck e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting

Tags: mount, fsck, recovery-mode

When I tried to run `fsck` on Ubuntu 18.04 recovery-mode I got the following message. Can anyone tell me why?

```
/lib/recocery-mode/recovery-menu: line 80: /etc/default/rcS: No such file or directory
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
/dev/sda4 is mounted
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't say what command you're using, so do it this way...

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda4` # replacing 4 with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Pretty sure they're not running a command directly, they're running the `fsck` menu item in the Ubuntu recovery mode menu.

Comment: If you have no usb stick... in grub, go to Advanced, then hit "e" to edit. Change the line starting "linux " and add " init=/bin/bash". Remove the lines starting "gfxmode " and "load_video" At the bash prompt, use df -h / to get the device path, then do, e.g. "fsck /dev/mapper/vg0-root" There is no systemd, so use alt+sysreq S U B to sync, unmount and reBoot since "reboot", "poweroff", etc won't work. I've put this here as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1938013 'll prob corrupt a lot of file systems.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1807537 => no fsck

Answer (score 3):

The error is telling you that you cannot use `e2fsck` while the target file system is mounted. You must unmount the file system first using `umount /dev/sda4`. If you're currently booted into a system that has that volume mounted it's likely that you cannot unmount it. You should probably use a USB stick and run `e2fsck` from that.