# Problem with Grub Recovery Menu on Xubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: recovery-mode

This is a duplicate of:
[fsck e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087205/fsck-e2fsck-cannot-continue-aborting/1087206)

because I can not comment there and it is obvious to me that people marking this as duplicate and the one's responding didn't really read/understand what the problem is.

On a fresh install of XUbuntu 18.04.2 if I used the "Extended Options for Ubuntu" and use any "...(revovery mode)" entry and in the following menu I choose "fsck check all filesystems" I initially got:

```
/lib/recocery-mode/recovery-menu: line 80: /etc/default/rcS: No such file or directory   
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1  
/dev/sda4 is mounted  
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

As there was no /etc/default/rcS on the installed Xubuntu 18.04.2 system and none on the Xubuntu live DVD, I checked an old 16.10 live DVD and that had a /etc/default/rcS, that bassically consisted of a bunch of options that were commented out. so I copied it over. and when I now try "... (recovery mode)" "fsck..." I get:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1  
/dev/sda4 is mounted  
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

Being a newbee I spent the last 2 days to try to find out how I can fix this permanently (I did file a bug-report). I need to get on the road with this laptop and when being on the road I need this "fsck..." menu to work as I can not run around with a big pile of paper of all the things I need to remember about bypassing problems in the boot process. I won't have access to the internet if that laptop fails. I did not want to try to copy the /lib/recocery-mode/ folder from the old 16.10 live DVD to 18.04.2 as I'm worried I might create damage that way and I just can not spend another 2 days searching with no useable result. I don't want to take the risk of booting an unchecked filesystem that might be corrupted (etc. because of power failure) either.

PS: english is not my mothertongue so please forgive me if I sound rude or anything. I'm just trying to state facts neutrally

Comment: If you need to `fsck` (file system check) your drives, it's easiest if they aren't mounted. The easiest way to accomplish this is to boot a 'live' system such as your Xubuntu install media; and `fsck` your hdd/sdd partitions from there. A `fsck` shouldn't be necessary unless something went wrong and the system was uncleanly rebooted/shutdown (though by default the system will do it for safety reasons every ~30th boot).  I don't understand the reason for your question though sorry.

Comment: The reason for my question is that obviously a part of the Xubuntu distribution is broken (has a bug) and being on the road I previously experienced that it is tricky to be dependant on things I have to take with me in addition to my laptop. It wouldn't be the first time of not finding them when I need them or of a DVD not working.'fsck' is part of the recovery menu and I want this to work as intended but being new to Xubuntu (I'm not new to computers) I don't know how to fix it myself.

Comment: Do you mean this bug?(https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1807537)  If not which bug? or if it's not yet reported, then please report it (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)

Comment: Oh I didn't find this one, despite searching excessively, when I filed https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/1833826  Yes it's the same.

Comment: fyi: I just marked your bug a duplicate (*and don't worry about not finding other bugs; I perfectly understand looking and not finding anything ...*).  Also if you disagree, please yell at me by commenting on the bug report and tell me why. Again: Thank you for taking the time to file & helping make Ubuntu better.  Alas I currently have no better fix than carrying a live 'install media' or really looking for why you have issues that create the need to fsck  (*though I do need sleep*)

Comment: thanks. I see no reason to disagree and I don't tend to yell at people just because of disagreeing ;-) I was just astonished about the duplicate mark in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087205/fsck-e2fsck-cannot-continue-aborting/1087206 because I found it obvious that is wasn't a duplicate and people didn't really get what it was about.

Comment: I was hoping that someone might be able to point out the script (or whatever it is) that does the wrong mount and just change that mount command. it can't be that a big deal. but I might be wrong on that.

Comment: I suspect it is as easy as you wish-it-to-be, but it's past midnight (my local time) so I need to go to bed. Hopefully you'll get help from someone else, or maybe tomorrow I'll be able to look again at into that bug-report.

Comment: If you have no usb stick... in grub, go to Advanced, then hit "e" to edit. Change the line starting "linux " and add " init=/bin/bash". Remove the lines starting "gfxmode " and "load_video"
At the bash prompt, use df -h / to get the device path, then do, e.g. "fsck /dev/mapper/vg0-root"
There is no systemd, so use alt+sysreq S U B to sync, unmount and reBoot since "reboot", "poweroff", etc won't work.
I've put this here as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1938013 will probably corrupt a lot of file systems.