# previous successful Kubuntu 20.04 LTSB EFI dual boot now boot looping?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu, uefi

One day my touchpad stopped taking input so I rebooted my laptop & haven't since been able to return to Kubuntu. When choosing it in GRUB I see (1) the OEM logo for ~1 sec, (2) the Kubuntu splash screen for ~1 sec, (3) the OEM logo forever. I can enter recovery & boot from a live USB. Things I have tried:

- enable & disable secure boot (shouldn't matter w/ EFI)
- disable hibernate & fast boot in Windows 10; performed a cold shut down
- my Ubuntu partition `/dev/nvme01p7` has the boot flag per [GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiFPz.jpg).
- `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` (Nvidia drivers I already had from the working installation)
- ran `dpkg` & `fsck` in recovery (Ubuntu partition is mounted, also noted [an error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1153259/problem-with-grub-recovery-menu-on-xubuntu-18-04-2) I'm ignoring)
- ran recommended `boot-repair`: see the logs for the [diagnostic](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/GQYyCg5bGk/) & [repair](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/BSFksGYNgz/)
- `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` [output](https://imgur.com/a/aKygEWu)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/606568/previous-successful-kubuntu-20-04-ltsb-efi-dual-boot-now-boot-looping

Comment: When you are logged in, open a terminal and type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` then copy the lines that start with **GRUB_** and then edit your question above and paste those lines into it please.

Comment: I didn't realize Drive worked that way @Nmath. I've fixed this.

Comment: Done @darth_epoxy.

Comment: OK will post an answer but it's not 100% however it's easier to read in the Answer box...

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub/`
Then swap out & change these lines;

> #GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
> GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="rhgb nosplash"

Commit the change in nano (Ctrl+O) then save over same name and exit (Ctrl+X).
Then type `sudo update-grub` then type `sudo shutdown -r now` and see what scrolls.

Comment: A sea of green, unfortunately: https://imgur.com/a/jKN3yNZ

Comment: Green is good and you see it because of the nosplash but can you see any errors in the output text? I can't read anything on your vidcap. You can ignore the green [OK] lines but try and screenshot or something so you can read the other lines. If anything looks like an error, type that in a comment ot edit your question.